# How to find the most commonly occurring combinations of Boolean variables by row in R

Tags: r

I have a series of 14 Boolean variables and I would like to find the top 3 combinations of 3 or more variables (where the value == 1).

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID   = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                 var1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 var2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                 var3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                 var4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                 var5 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                 )
df

> df
  ID var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1  1    0    1    0    1    0
2  2    0    0    0    1    0
3  3    1    0    1    1    0
4  4    1    1    1    1    1
5  5    1    1    1    1    1
6  6    0    1    1    0    0
7  7    0    1    0    1    1
8  8    1    0    0    1    1
```

I found a solution to bring all column names together per unique occurance:

```
# Bring to long format
df_long <- df %>%  
  melt(id.vars = "ID")  

# Collapse the variables that have a '1' together per row
df_combo <- ddply(df_long, "ID", summarize, 
                   combos = paste(variable[value == 1], collapse = "/")) 



> df_combo
  ID                   combos
1  1                var2/var4
2  2                     var4
3  3           var1/var3/var4
4  4 var1/var2/var3/var4/var5
5  5 var1/var2/var3/var4/var5
6  6                var2/var3
7  7           var2/var4/var5
8  8           var1/var4/var5
```

If I only wanted counts on unique combinations this would be fine, but I would like to know the number of times each combination of 3 or more variables occurs, even in cases where other variables also occur.  The combination (var1/var4/var5) occurs 3 times in the above example, but twice it occurs next to two other variables.

There must be an easy way to extract this information, just can't think of it.  Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attempt, using `combn` as the workhorse function.

```
arr <- which(df[-1] == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
tmp <- tapply(arr[,"col"], arr[,"row"], 
           FUN=function(x) if (length(x) >= 3) combn(x,3, simplify=FALSE) )
tmp <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, unlist(tmp, rec=FALSE)))
aggregate(count ~ . , cbind(tmp, count=1), sum)

##   X1 X2 X3 count
##1   1  2  3     2
##2   1  2  4     2
##3   1  3  4     3
##4   2  3  4     2
##5   1  2  5     2
##6   1  3  5     2
##7   2  3  5     2
##8   1  4  5     3
##9   2  4  5     3
##10  3  4  5     2
```